# Boostrap background image in all web page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a asp.net web form with a master page. I have three divs ... One with class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top", other with class="main-content" and the last one with class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom". I need to put a background image in the complete page ... no matter the divs .. What code should write? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use CSS to set a background image on the `body` element.  You can use the background-size property to ensure the image always occupies the full area.

```
body { background: url(your/image/path.jpg); background-size: cover; }
```

Comment: I have now one little thing .. between divs separation line appears.  How I can remove it?

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez I'd start a new question as that's a completely different thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting it in the "Body" section via CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/3jnsc0uu/

```
body {
    background: url("IMAGE URL HERE");
}
```